# Class instantiation above vs below class declaration

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, instantiation

I have a class called UserController which is instantiated above its own declaration, by an ajax call to UserController.php. It works, as expected.

```
<?php
new UserController();

class UserController{
  //constructor
  //methods
}
?>
```

Now I want to provide some common functionality to all of my controllers, and have done so by extending a baseController.

```
<?php
//include BaseController
new UserController();

class UserController extends BaseController{
  //constructor
  //methods
}
?>
```

However, I get this message when the instantiation is attempted:

**Fatal error: Class 'UserController' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\controllers\UserController.php**

If I move the instantiation to after the declaration. It all works fine again.

```
<?php
//include BaseController

class UserController extends BaseController{
  //constructor
  //methods
}

new UserController();
?>
```

Can someone please shed some light on this?

Why does instantiating the UserController class need to be done after its declaration in this case, but can be done before the declaration if not extending another class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs :

> Unless autoloading is used, then classes must be defined before they are used. If a class extends another, then the parent class must be declared before the child class structure. This rule applies to classes that inherit other classes and interfaces.

[Reference here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php)

and `include` is not autoloading ... so there is your problem

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I should have / could have found it in the docs. However, it's difficult to find that one specific peculiarity when you don't know exactly what to look for.